# Create Directional Arrows on highmaps

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

How can i create a directional arrow from one country to another country in highmaps, is there a way to modify the mapline.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Defaulty it is not build-in, but you can use bubble serie (with the same min/maxSize) define points as object which contain relations by any id or arrays. Then run renderer and add missing lines with arrows.

Docs:
 - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path